# Connect to LDAP server

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryentry

I'd like to implement a function that searches an ldap server (name, phone number etc.)

Here's what I wrote (the server address is a phony one, but the real one has the same pattern)

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://aet7ldap.phony.com")                 
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
var test = ds.FindAll();
```

I know that there are other constructors (string path, string user, string password), but I don't know my username or password and I'm not sure if I need one. So please help me figure out how to do it without these parameters (if that is possible).

I've tried to write a filter as well but that's another thing, because first I need to get my connection right. But can I assume that I have to use these parameters (or column names?) I keep reading everywhere (such as 'gn' for given name and so on)?

Comment: Is it a "generic" LDAP server, or are you using Active Directory specifically?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. I was just told that I'm supposed to 'connect' the program to this database. I've never even heard of ldap before. I don't know if that helps, but the way the server is used is you access the company intranet, type in 'aet' as URL and you are redirected to a form, where you enter the first name, last name, phone number etc. of the person you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're trying to connect to Active Directory using the Directory entry method to find a user, you haven't mentioned if you're doing anything to the user you're looking for once they're found, so I'll just give you code that finds the user for you.

```
using(DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://servername/DC=phony,DC=com"))
using(DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
{
    ds.Filter="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName="username"))";
    //I don't know exactly what criteria you're using to find the user
    ds.Filter="(&(objectClass=user)(distinguishedname="")(givenname=""))"
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

    //performing the search and assigning the result to result
    SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        using(DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {
            //put code here to deal with the user as you see fit.
        }
        lblOutput.Text = "User " + userName + " was found.";
    }
}
```

The Filter is the most important part to find the user you're looking for, the `&` means `and` so in the first example I gave in the code above, you're looking for an object with the class user `AND` the username `username`. Its easy enough to figure out. Here is a link to a list of all Active Directory attributes, you should be able to find what you're looking for there. 
http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes.htm

Regards,
Tory Hill

Comment: Hi Tory, thank you so much for your help. However, I still had problems. I would get a COMException everytime the directorysearcher was called to find results. I then tried the following constructor:
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://aet7ldap.phony.com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.None); and apparently that did the trick. I can now look for users and add them to a datagrid, which is all I wanted to do. But thanks again!